# Encryption compatibility between Obj-C and VB.Net

Tags: ios, vb.net, aes

There are about 100,000 different possible ways to encrypt a string. Using standards like AES, CBC, and PKCS7 make things easier - but there are still problems with IVs. Salts, Encoding, etc. (As noted on [www.Crypto.Stackexchange.com](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/3022/what-is-the-difference-between-these-aes-encryption-methods))

For my iOS project (Obj-C), I'm using the [FBEncryptor project](https://github.com/dev5tec/FBEncryptor) which is an easy and well documented way to encrypt strings. However, I need code that will be able to decrypt that iOS AES string generated by FBEncryptor on a Windows platform - preferably VB.NET.

I have yet to find another project for VB.NET that is compatible with FBEncryptor.

**Does anyone know of any VB.NET encryption projects that work with FBEncryptor? If not, then what do I need to do to make the Rijndael Managed library (provided by Microsoft) work with FBEncryptor?**

My VB.NET Code using [Rijndael Managed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rijndaelmanaged.aspx):

```
Imports System.Security
Imports System.Security.Cryptography
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
Imports System.Text


Module Encrypt2
Public saltBytes As Byte()
Dim hashAlgorithm As String = "SHA1"

Public Sub GenerateSalt()
    ' Define min and max salt sizes.
    Dim minSaltSize As Integer
    Dim maxSaltSize As Integer

    minSaltSize = 8
    maxSaltSize = 8

    ' Generate a random number for the size of the salt.
    Dim random As Random
    random = New Random()

    Dim saltSize As Integer
    saltSize = random.Next(minSaltSize, maxSaltSize)

    ' Allocate a byte array, which will hold the salt.
    saltBytes = New Byte(saltSize - 1) {}

    ' Initialize a random number generator.
    Dim rng As RNGCryptoServiceProvider
    rng = New RNGCryptoServiceProvider()

    ' Fill the salt with cryptographically strong byte values.
    rng.GetNonZeroBytes(saltBytes)
End Sub

Public Function Encrypt(ByVal plainText As String, ByVal keyword As String) As String
    Dim hashAlgorithm As String = "SHA1"
    Dim passwordIterations As Integer = 128
    Dim initVector As String = "@7781157e2629b09"
    Dim keySize As Integer = 256

    Dim initVectorBytes As Byte() = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(initVector)

    Dim plainTextBytes As Byte() = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(plainText)

    GenerateSalt()

    Dim password As New Rfc2898DeriveBytes(keyword, saltBytes, passwordIterations)

    Dim keyBytes As Byte() = password.GetBytes(keySize \ 8)
    Dim symmetricKey As New RijndaelManaged()

    symmetricKey.Mode = CipherMode.CBC

    Dim encryptor As ICryptoTransform = symmetricKey.CreateEncryptor(keyBytes, initVectorBytes)

    Dim memoryStream As New MemoryStream()
    Dim cryptoStream As New CryptoStream(memoryStream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write)

    cryptoStream.Write(plainTextBytes, 0, plainTextBytes.Length)
    cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock()
    Dim cipherTextBytes As Byte() = memoryStream.ToArray()
    memoryStream.Close()
    cryptoStream.Clear()

    Dim cipherText As String = Convert.ToBase64String(cipherTextBytes)

    Return (cipherText)

End Function

Public Function Decrypt(ByVal cipherText As String, ByVal keyword As String) As String

    Dim hashAlgorithm As String = "SHA1"

    Dim passwordIterations As Integer = 128
    Dim initVector As String = "@7781157e2629b09"
    Dim keySize As Integer = 256

    ' Convert strings defining encryption key characteristics into Byte
    ' arrays. Let us assume that strings only contain ASCII codes.
    ' If strings include Unicode characters, use Unicode, UTF7, or UTF8
    ' encoding

    Dim initVectorBytes As Byte() = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(initVector)

    ' Convert the Ciphertext into a Byte array
    Dim cipherTextBytes As Byte() = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(cipherText)

    ' First we must create a password, from which the key will be 
    ' derived. This password will be generated from the specified
    ' passphrase and salt value. The password will be created using 
    ' the specified hash algorithm. Password creation can be done in 
    ' several iterations
    GenerateSalt()
    Dim password As New Rfc2898DeriveBytes(keyword, saltBytes, passwordIterations)

    ' Use the password to generate pseudo-random bytes for the encryption
    ' key. Specify the size of the key in bytes (instead of bits)

    Dim keyBytes As Byte() = password.GetBytes(keySize \ 8)

    ' Create uninitialized Rijndael encryption object

    Dim symmetricKey As New RijndaelManaged()

    ' It is reasonable to set encryption mode to Cipher Block Chaining
    ' (CBC). Use default options for other symmetric key parameters.
    symmetricKey.Mode = CipherMode.CBC

    ' Generate decryptor from the existing key bytes and initialization
    ' vector. Key size will be defined based on the number of the key
    'bytes

    Dim decryptor As ICryptoTransform = symmetricKey.CreateDecryptor(keyBytes, initVectorBytes)

    ' Define memory stream which will be used to hold encrypted data.

    Dim memoryStream As New MemoryStream(cipherTextBytes)

    ' Define cryptographic stream (always user Read mode for encryption).
    Dim cryptoStream As New CryptoStream(memoryStream, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read)


    ' Since at this point we don't know what the size of decrypted data
    ' will be, allocate the buffer long enough to hold ciphertext;
    ' plaintext is never longer than ciphertext
    Dim plainTextBytes As Byte() = New Byte(cipherTextBytes.Length - 1) {}

    ' Start decrypting.
    Dim decryptedByteCount As Integer = cryptoStream.Read(plainTextBytes, 0, plainTextBytes.Length)

    ' Close both streams
    memoryStream.Close()
    cryptoStream.Close()

    ' Convert decrypted data into a string
    ' Let us assume that the original plaintext string was UTF8-Encoded.
    Dim plainText As String = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(plainTextBytes, 0, decryptedByteCount)

    ' Return the decrypted string
    Return (plainText)


End Function

End Module
```

You'll notice that the IV is static and that the password iterations are low. This is because I'm not sure how to generate the IV in the same method as FBEncryptor. You may also notice that when attempting to decrypt, there are problems with the byte length.

Any help will be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Can you show us the Obj-C code you use to encrypt the string?

Comment: The Obj-C code is available at the following GitHub Project: https://github.com/dev5tec/FBEncryptor

Comment: Yeah, I saw their code.  But I was curious how you were calling it from your program.  There seem to be at least two sets of API's there, and it will make a difference which one you are calling.

Comment: Hmmm... there are multiple methods (not sure about the API). One set of methods is used to convert the data between Base64 and Strings. The other set is used to encrypt and decrypt the Base64 Data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One note. I looked in FBEncryptor. It uses some bad practices. So, if security is important for you I would recommend read up a little bit more regarding that and choose another code which does encryption (or write it on your own).

FBEncryptor does following for encryption
a) Convert string to byte array (based on UTF8 encoding)
b) Convert key to byte array (based on UTF encoding).
c) Copy only first 16 bytes of key 
d) Create IV which is 16 butes of 0x00
e) Encrypt byte array from item a) using AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding with IV created in d)
f) The resulting encrypted data is converted to Base64

And it does following for decryption
a) Convert encrypt string from Base64 to byte array
b) Convert key to byte array (based on UTF encoding).
c) Copy only first 16 bytes of key 
d) Create IV which is 16 butes of 0x00
e) Decrypt byte array from item a) using AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding with IV created in d)
f) Convert encrypted data from e) to a string using UTF8 encoding

You should do exactly the same thing in VB.NET. I think you have almost all parts
- You will need to drop all SHA1 and salt related stuff and use equivalent of step b).
And you will need to research PKCS7Padding for VB.NET

Comment: I've removed all hash and salt related things, and any related errors but I'm having issues with the key and IV. I can't figure out how to convert the key to a byte array (and do you mean UTF or UTF8?)? Any tips? I get a 'Specified key is not a valid size for this algorithm.' error when trying to encrypt now.

Comment: I meant UTF8. Regarding key size. I didn't put it correctly first time. What you need to do is to create a 16 bytes arrays of 0x00 and copy there key converted to UTF-8. So, as examepl, if key converted to UTF-8 will be longer than 16 bytes, you will copy only 16 bytes. If it will be shorter than 16 bytes, you will copy as many bytes as available.

Comment: This is all true if OP is calling encryptBase64String, but things are slightly different if OP is calling encryptData directly instead.

Comment: I've taken out Salt and Hash, added IV generation, and pretty much rewritten it. When decrypting with FBEncryptor I still get nothing. No errors, no text, just blank. The new code is here: http://pastie.org/4676552 Could you take a look. Thanks!

Comment: 2RazorSharp: a) Good catch regarding key size (i wrote it that it's 16 bytes, you set it 256 bit, which is 32 bytes and it's correct). I think your problem is for loop in GetKey. I believe the code should look like this : http://pastie.org/4696440 You code has two problems (it doesn't add zeroes at the end of array and because of Mod operation it will go through kRaw several times, if there is not enough bytes to fill a key)

Comment: @VictorRonin I think you're right, and you've been very helpful thus far.... but the code you posted on paste.org/4696440 generate an error at runtime: The specified key is not a valid size for this algorithm. It occurs on the following line and is related to the GetKey method: result.Key = realKey

Comment: 2RazonSharp: Can you set a breakpoint in result.Key = realKey and check what is the size of realKey array/list and also check result.KeySize. Per my understanding array should be 32 bytes and KeySize = 256 (32 bytes * 8)

Comment: @VictorRonin I tried to set a conditional breakpoint (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/saraford/archive/2008/06/17/did-you-know-you-can-set-conditional-breakpoints-239.aspx) but it won't let me add a condition. Is there an easier way I can contact you for clarification?

Comment: 2RazorSharp: You can find me email in my profile. Send me an email.